# Python Multiple Inheritance/Mixin

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I have the following problem:

```
class A:
    animal = 'gerbil'

    def __init__(self):
        self.result = self.calculate_animal()

    def calculate_animal(self):
        print(self.animal)
        return self.animal

class B(A):
    animal = 'zebra'

    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
```

Now, I want a certain set of subclasses from A, to implement a new function that calculates something different with the animal, like so:

```
class CapitalizeAnimal:

    def calculate_animal(self):
        self.animal = self.animal.upper()
        # I need to call some version of super().self.animal,
        # but how will this Mixin class know of class A?


class C(A, #CapitalizeAnimal?):
    animal = 'puma':

    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
```

How do I get `class C` to implement the `CapitalizeAnimal` version of `calculate_animal`, while keeping its animal as `puma`? I'm confused at how the Mixin class will be able to call a super() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the parent classes is important, you should do it like so:

```
class C(CapitalizeAnimal, A):
     animal = 'puma'

     def __init__(self):
         super(C, self).__init__()
```

More info can be found by reading about the [MRO](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) (Method Resolution Order).

---

Also, `super` only works with [new style classes](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-new-style-class), so you should make A inherit `object` (unless of course you are using Python 3).

Comment: Because A is second, won't its version of calculate override CapitalizeAnimal's implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I made my question more complex. I'm not sure how CapitalizedAnimal would handle knowing of the attributes of class C, and return a super() on class A

Comment: @Manny D: yes if you make the inheritance like this: `class C(A, CapitalizeAnimal)` so the `A.CapitalizeAnimal` will be called only, unless if you are calling already `super` in `A.CapitalizeAnimal` which in this case all the mro will be traversed.

Comment: @Jasie: if you want to call only the `calculate_animal` of `A` so you add in your Mixin `A.calculate_animal(self)` , but if you want to call all the `calculate_animal` of classes that are in the MRO so use `super` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `B` and `C` don't need `__init__()` if the only action is calling the super `__init__`.

To your question: Have you tried `class C(A, CapitalizeAnimal):` and/or `class C(A, CapitalizeAnimal):`? I.e., omitting the `#` and the `?`?